# Putting jsons to dataframes automatically in spark

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have multiple jsons in .gz file. I try to parse them into rdds and then to dataframes. I make it not in the best way:

```
rdd =sc.textFile(path).map(json.loads).map(get_values)
```

where get_values function is something like this:

```
def get_values(data): 
    try:
        time = data['time']
    except Exception:
        time = None
    try:
        place = data['data']['place']
    except Exception:
        place = None
return time, place
```

The problem is that several jsons are different, some of them contains several categories, some not and it's difficult to write this function 'by hands' to make dataframe contain all the keys.
The question is: are there any approaches/functions to automize this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read json files with:

```py
df = spark.read.json(path)
```

Spark automatically tries to infer the schema and you can see it using

```py
df.printSchema
```

If you have multi-line json use the option `multiline = true`.

You can learn more about reading json files with Spark in the [official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-json.html).

---

#### Parsing json from string in Spark

As a general advice, to parse a json from a string in Spark avoid using `map` and `json.loads` (or similar functions).

There is a faster solution already available in Spark: [`from_json` function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_json).

Comment: actually it's not what i need. I need to parse all "subkeys" (keys of dictionaries in values)

Answer (score 0):

Since your input `data` is a dictionary, I guess you could use this function :

```
from functools import reduce

def get_values(data):
    values = data.values()
    while any([isinstance(value, dict) for value in values]):
        not_dicts = list(filter(lambda value: not isinstance(value, dict), values))
        dicts = list(filter(lambda value: isinstance(value, dict), values))
        values = not_dicts + reduce(lambda l1, l2: l1+l2, [dict_.values() for dict_ in dicts])
    return values

d = {1:1,
     2:2,
     3:{'a':4,
        'b': 5,
        'c': {'z': 6}
       }
    }
get_values(d)

[1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: what is reduce? "name 'reduce' is not defined"

Comment: This code was in Python 2.7. In Python 3, filter and reduce behave differently. I edited the post to be compatible with Python 3.